# Defining an object in another model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, undefined, relationship

I have migrated the `:bank_name` and `:bank_account` objects in `User model`.

I want two objects can be define from the `Listings model` in the listings/view to the `User model` columns.

I have already done (`belongs_to`, `has_many`)relations between two models.

But when I filled the `bank_name` and `bank_account` **text_fields** in Listing/view, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `bank_name' for #Listing:400123298
```

Here is my **listing/view** code:

```
<%= form_for(@listing, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
...
   <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :bank_name %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :bank_name, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :bank_account %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :bank_account, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
</end>
```

**listing/controller:**

```
def new
    @listing = Listing.new
  end

 def create
      @listing = Listing.new(listing_params)
      @listing.user_id = current_user.id
      @listing.user_id = User.bank_name.build(params[:bank_name])
      @listing.user_id = User.bank_account.build(params[:bank_account])
end
```

Comment: If i understood you correctly, what you are trying to do is called 'nested models` in Rails & you are doing it wrong. I think you should take a look at this http://asciicasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Comment: No actually. I d like to another model refer an object that owns the actual object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues for you

---

**Nested**

As mentioned in the comments, what you're looking at is a `nested model` structure.

Simply, this means you'll be able to create an associative model from your "parent" - giving you the ability to define the attributes you need in your "parent" model, passing them through to the nested. This functionality is handled by [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) in your parent model

The [best resource you can use is this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) (only the start):
[image]

--

**Fix**

Here's how you can fix the problem:

```
#app/models/listing.rb
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :bank_account
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :bank_account
end

#app/models/bank_account.rb
class BankAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end


#app/controllers/listings_controller.rb
class ListingsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @listing = current_user.listings.new
      @listing.user.build_bank_account
   end

   def create
      @listing = Listing.new listing_params
      @listing.save
   end

   private

   def listing_params
      params.require(:listing).permit(:listing, :params, user_attributes: [ bank_account_attributes: [] ])
   end
end
```

This will help you do the following:

```
#app/views/listings/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @listing do |f| %>
    ...
    <%= f.fields_for :user do |u| %>
       <%= u.fields_for :bank_account do |b| %>
           <%= b.text_field :name %>
           <%= b.text_field :number %>
       <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

There is a slight twist to this tail, in that I'm not sure whether your passing of attributes through to your `User` model. This would be okay *if* the user was being created at the same time as your other attributes, but as it isn't, we may need to refactor the process of passing the nested data through

If this does not work, please comment & we can work to fix it!

Comment: Hello Rich!  I m getting the following error: unknown attribute: user_id  the line that i get the error is: @listing.user.build_bank_information

Comment: Hmmm -do you have `user_id` in that table?

Comment: You re right! It works.I create a listing with bank_name and bank_account. But when i make a query in rails console. There is no bank_information table updated. I m using devise gem. So i have updated the devise sanitizer for bank information table in application controller but nothing changed.

Comment: Hmm okay- so you added `user_id` column? Can you show me the params which are passed from your form to Rails backend?

Comment: <%= f.fields_for :user do |u| %>
       <%= u.fields_for :bank_information do |b| %>
           <%= b.label :bank_name %>
           <%= b.text_field :bank_name %>
           <%= b.label :bank_account %>
           <%= b.text_field :bank_account %>
       <% end %>
    <% end %>

Comment: Thanks - but the params are stored in your log! If go to `/log/development.log`, you'll find the params passed in the form submission. If you can edit your answer & paste them, it will be the best

Comment: [1m[35mUser Load (0.2ms)[0m SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 9 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1 Unpermitted parameters: id I m trying to put :id inside the listing/controller strong parameters but still got the following unpermitted: id error. Strong parameter line is: def listing_params params.require(:listing).permit(:listing, :name, :description, :price, :image, :category_id, :postal_code, :location, :params, user_attributes: [ bank_information_attributes: [:bank_account, :bank_name, :id] ]) end

Comment: Hmm can you post the params hash which is posted? This will show us where the `id` is passed, allowing us to amend your strong params

Comment: def listing_params
      params.require(:listing).permit(:listing, :name, :description, :price, :image, :category_id, :postal_code, :location, :product_condition, :gender_id, :age_range, :delivery_information, :params, user_attributes: [ bank_information_attributes: [:bank_account, :bank_name, :id] ])
    end

Comment: No, that's the `strong_params` function -- I meant the parameters sent to your controller from your form! :)

Comment: Is it very obvious that I m a newbie :) Here is I guess:  <%= f.fields_for :user do |u| %>
       <%= u.fields_for :bank_information do |b| %>
           <%= b.label :bank_name %>
           <%= b.text_field :bank_name %>
           <%= b.label :bank_account %>
           <%= b.text_field :bank_account %>
       <% end %>
    <% end %>

Comment: lol don't worry about being new! You almost had what I need when you posted `[1m[35mUser Load (0.2ms)[0m SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 9 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1 Unpermitted parameters: id` -- Underneath that, Rails will display the actual parameters which were sent in the request. I need to see them!

Comment: [1m[36mUser Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 9]]
Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `image_content_type`
  [1m[35mSQL (0.7ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "listings" ("age_range", "category_id", "created_at", "delivery_information", "description", "image_content_type", "image_file_name", "image_file_size", "image_updated_at", "location", "name", "postal_code", "price", "product_condition", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["age_range", ""], ["category_id", 3], continues...

Comment: ["created_at", "2014-09-12 10:43:18.079664"], ["delivery_information", ""], ["description", "denene"], ["image_content_type", "image/jpeg"], ["image_file_name", "the_legend_of_zelda_triforce_lamp_by_ericmargera-d5sj7bn.jpg"], ["image_file_size", 55105], ["image_updated_at", "2014-09-12 10:43:17.658163"], ["location", "istanbul"], ["name", "denein"], ["postal_code", 434343], ["price", 300.0], ["product_condition", ""], ["updated_at", "2014-09-12 10:43:18.079664"], ["user_id", 9]] . I hope that is true :)

Comment: Can you check it out? Thx!